# Correct way to Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing

I've been practicing Unit Testing over the last couple of weeks but I'm not sure I'm testing the correct way.

The system I'm trying to test looks like this on the live system:

- Quantity
- Unit Net Sales Price
- Net Total
- Sales Tax @ 20%
- Total

I filled the fields with the following data:

- Quantity = 6
- Unit Net Sale Price = 22.00
- Net Total = 132.00
- Sales Tax @ 20% = 26.40
- Total = 158

I created a Unit Test using the assertEquals which passes:

```
    public void testTaxCalculation3() throws Exception{
            float quantity = 6;
            float netSalePrice = 22.00f;
            float taxPercent = 20.00f;

            float totalNetPrice = netSalePrice * quantity; //6 multiply 22 = 132.0
            float taxAmount = (totalNetPrice * taxPercent) / 100; //132.00 multiply by 20 = 2640 divided by 100 = 26.4
            float totalPrice;
        totalPrice = totalNetPrice + taxAmount; //132 plus 26.4

        Assert.assertEquals((float) 158.40, totalPrice);
    }
```

Is this the right way to write the Unit Test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encapsulate the tax calculation logic in a method and then write a unit test on that method (or even better - write the test first and the method later).

In your case, you should have something like this:

```
// Your tax method
float TaxCalculation(float quantity, float netSalePrice, float taxPercent)
{
  float totalNetPrice = netSalePrice * quantity; 
  float taxAmount = (totalNetPrice * taxPercent) / 100; 
  float totalPrice = totalNetPrice + taxAmount;
  return totalPrice;
}

// Your tax method test
// I'm assuming NUnit here
[Test]
[TestCase(6, 22.00, 20.00, 158.40)]
public void TaxCalculation(float quantity, float netSalePrice, float taxPercent, float expectedTotalPrice)
{
  float totalPrice = TaxCalculation(quantity, netSalePrice, taxPercent);
  Assert.AreEqual(totalPrice, expectedTotalPrice);
}
```

Comment: thanks TAMTAM, that helps me to understand a bit better than what I thought

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are currently testing the test code itself which will provide you with minimal benefits. Unit testing is a technique you can use to rapidly test pieces of production code. Using this technique, you don't just copy paste the "real" code into the test but rather you call the production logic from your test code. In that way whenever something changes in your production code, the tests will fail and will notify you that some assumption you have codified in the test is violated by your changes in the production code.

To recap: don't duplicate the calculations into the test, but rather call the real code from the unit test and verify whether the production code calculates the total price correctly.

Comment: thanks prgmtc, This helps me to understand where it is I'm going wrong